# HashMap using streams and substring

Tags: java, substring, java-stream

I am wondering how to achieve the following.

> "t12345-g1234-o1234"

I have a line that contains multiple fields delimited by an hyphen and the field is formed by its identifier(first letter) and value.

How can I achieve an Map like the one below using java 8 streams.

> {"t","12345"} , {"g","1234"}, {"o","1234"}

EDIT

I have tried the following, but I don't understand how to grab the substring information.

```
Arrays.stream(line.split("-"))
.collect(Collectors.toMap(String::substring(0,1),String::substring(1));
```

Comment: You have tried anything yourself?

Comment: I have started with this: "Arrays.stream(line.split(";")).collect(Collectors.toMap", but didn't go further

Comment: I suggest you go ahead, edit the question and post what you have already tried.

Comment: why would you want to split a string by `;` when the character is not even present in it? :) and then the difference between method reference and lambda ussage.

Comment: it was just a typo, sorry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.toMap`

```
Map<String, String> result = Arrays.stream(s.split("-"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(part -> part.substring(0, 1),
                    part -> part.substring(1)));
```

The first argument to `toMap` is the keyMapper. It picks the key as the first character in the split string part. `part.substring(0, 1)` - It will return the substring starting at index 0 of length 1 (which is the first character).

The second argument is the valueMapper. It is the rest that follows the first character. `part.substring(1)` - Returns the substring starting at index 1 (since no end index is specified, it will be taken as `part.length`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(str.split("-"))
                .map(s -> Pair.of(s.substring(0, 1), s.substring(1)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getKey, Pair::getValue));
```

I've used [Pair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) here.